# Adding new classes to SGDClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm currently using `partial_fit` with [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) to fit a model to predict the hashtags on images.

The problem I'm having is that SGDClassifier requires specifying `classes` upfront. This is ok to fit a model offline but I'd like to add new classes online when observing new hashtags. Currently, I need to retrain a new model from scratch to accommodate the new classes.

Is there a way to have SGDClassifier accept new classes without having to retrain a new model? Or would I be better off training a separate binary SGDClassifier for each hashtag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashtags are usually just tags, thus one object can have many of them. In such setting there is no multiclass scenario - and you should have just a single SGD binary classifier per tag. You can obviously fit more complex models taking into account reasoning between tags, but SGD is not duing so, thus using it in a provided setting does not make any more sense than just having N distinct classifiers.